# Footer div not display in Portrait mode in iPad or iPhone

Tags: html, css

I required "Content-footer" div fixed. If I show my page in i-phone or i-pad in landscape mode it is working fine but in portrait mode "Content-footer" div not display. You just check my code in **"Google Chrome Device mode"** and check "Portrait mode" and "Landscape mode".
I attached two screenshot.
 **"Content-footer" div displays in landscape mode.**
[image: Content-footer" div displays in landscape mode]

**"Content-footer" div not displays in Portrait mode.**[image: Content-footer" div not displays in Portrait mode]

> Html Code

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <div class="Header-wrapper">
            <h3>Header data</h3>
        </div>
    </header>
    <content>
        <div class="Content-Wrapper">
            <div style="Content-Data">
                <h3>Content Data</h3>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Content-footer">
            <h3>Content Data Footer Fixed</h3>
</div>
    </content>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

> Style

```
.Header-wrapper
{
  width:1200px; 
  background-color:#ffb3b3;
}
.Content-Wrapper
{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:1200px;
  position:relative;
  min-height:600px;
  height:auto;
}
.Content-Data
{
  min-height:600px;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.Content-footer
{
  bottom:0;
  background-color:orange; 
  position:fixed;
  width:1200px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same code as in your question? I have no problems in portrait / landscape.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKdJza

Comment: Thanks for fast reply but don't show this code in any online editor. Just create one html page and see it Chrome Devise mode. This code completed working in jsfiddle or any other editor. But not working in html page.

Comment: @Pimskie, do post it as an answer. Nice finding.

Comment: .Header-wrapper and .Content-Wrapper a width of 100% is working fine.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (and i don't know why..), when the `.Header-wrapper` and `.Content-Wrapper` are wider than the viewport (eg. wider than 1024px, iPad landscape), the footer is pushed out of view.

Try giving `.Header-wrapper` and `.Content-Wrapper` a width of 100% for example. That works

Comment: Thanks for help. but i have to use  "px" instead of "%" for width in my project. please give me other solutions for this .

Comment: Set it to the desired pixels and use media queries to make sure they aren't higher than the viewport width.